# popup window is not displayed

Tags: android, popupwindow

i have this java class:

```
    package com.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Ajax extends Activity{

    TextView TVajax;
    Context context;
    Button hint1,hint2,check,used,right;
    EditText answer; 
    int points=1;
    final int ALERT_DIALOG=1;
    PopupWindow popUp;
    TextView title,message;
    Button close,stats;



    public static boolean right(String[] a,String b)
    //in=String array and string
    //out=if the string is equal/close to one of the strings in the array-true else-false
    {
        boolean flag=false;
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        {   
            int count=0;
            if(a[i].length()==b.length()){
                if(a[i].equalsIgnoreCase(b))
                    return true;
                else{if(a[i].length()>6){
                    for(int j=0;j<a[i].length();j++)
                    {
                        if(a[i].charAt(j)==b.charAt(j))
                            count++;
                    }
                    if(count==a[i].length()-1)
                        flag=true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return flag;
    }

    public void messageBox(String[] a,String b)
    //in=get the answer of the "right" method and the present name
    //out=if true-change the "TVajax" to the present name and pop up a message; false-nothing
    {   
        Context context=getApplicationContext();
        boolean f=false;
        if(!right(a,b)){
            if(b.length()<=6){
                for(int i=0;i<a.length&&!f;i++)
                {   
                    int fl=-1;
                    int count=0;
                    int diff=a[i].length()-b.length();
                    switch(diff){
                    case 0:
                        for(int j=0;j<a[i].length();j++)
                        {
                            if(a[i].charAt(j)==b.charAt(j))
                                count++;
                            if(count==a[i].length()-1){
                                f=true;
                                CharSequence text = "Almost perfect,you'r close!";
                                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                                Toast popuptoast=Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                                popuptoast.show();
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        if(a[i].startsWith(b)||a[i].endsWith(b)){
                            f=true;
                            CharSequence text = "Almost perfect,you'r close!";
                            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                            Toast popuptoast=Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                            popuptoast.show();
                        }
                        break;
                    case -1:
                        if(b.startsWith(a[i])||b.endsWith(a[i])){
                            f=true;
                            CharSequence text = "Almost perfect,you'r close!";
                            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                            Toast popuptoast=Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                            popuptoast.show();
                        }
                        else{

                        for(int j=1;j<a[i].length()&&fl==-1;j++)
                        {   
                            if(a[i].charAt(j)!=b.charAt(j)&&a[i].charAt(j)==b.charAt(j+1)){
                                fl=j;
                                if(a[i].substring(0, j).equalsIgnoreCase(b.substring(0, j))&&a[i].substring(j).equalsIgnoreCase(b.substring(j+1))){
                                    f=true;
                                    CharSequence text = "Almost perfect,you'r close!";
                                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                                    Toast popuptoast=Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                                    popuptoast.show();
                                }
                            }


                        }
                    }
                    default:;
                    }
                }

            }else{
                for(int i=0;i<a.length&&!f;i++)
                {   
                    int fm=-1,sm=-1;
                    int diff=a[i].length()-b.length();
                    int count=0;
                    switch(diff){
                    case 0:
                        for(int j=0;j<a[i].length();j++)
                        {
                            if(a[i].charAt(j)==b.charAt(j))
                                count++;
                            if(count==a[i].length()-2){
                                f=true;
                                CharSequence text = "Almost perfect,you'r close!";
                                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                                Toast popuptoast=Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                                popuptoast.show();
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        if(b.startsWith(a[i])||b.endsWith(a[i])){
                            f=true;
                            CharSequence text = "Almost perfect,you'r close!";
                            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                            Toast popuptoast=Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                            popuptoast.show();
                        }                           
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        if(a[i].indexOf(b)!=-1){
                            f=true;
                            CharSequence text = "Almost perfect,you'r close!";
                            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                            Toast popuptoast=Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                            popuptoast.show();
                        }
                        break;
                    case -1:
                        for(int j=0;j<a[i].length()&&(fm==-1||sm==-1);j++)
                        {
                            if(a[i].charAt(j)!=b.charAt(j)&&fm==-1)
                                fm=j;
                            if(a[i].charAt(j)!=b.charAt(j)&&fm!=-1)
                                sm=j;
                        }
                        if(b.substring(0,fm).equalsIgnoreCase(a[i].substring(0, fm))&&b.substring(fm+1, sm).equalsIgnoreCase(a[i].substring(fm, sm))&&b.substring(sm+1).equalsIgnoreCase(a[i].substring(sm))){
                            f=true;
                            CharSequence text = "Almost perfect,you'r close!";
                            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                            Toast popuptoast=Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                            popuptoast.show();
                        }
                        break;
                    case -2:
                        if(b.indexOf(a[i])!=-1){
                            f=true;
                            CharSequence text = "Almost perfect,you'r close!";
                            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                            Toast popuptoast=Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                            popuptoast.show();
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(!f){
                CharSequence text = "wrong answer,try again!";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                Toast popuptoast=Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                popuptoast.show();
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ajax);
        initialize();
        check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String show="Amsterdamsche Football Club Ajax NV";
                String[] answers={"amsterdamsche football club ajax nv","ajax","afc","afc ajax","afc ajax amsterdam","amsterdam","ajax amsterdam","ajax afc","ajax amsterdam afc","afc amsterdam","amsterdam ajax afc","amsterdam ajax"};
                answer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ETajax);
                String answera=answer.getText().toString();
                if(right(answers,answera)){
                    TVajax.setText(show);
                    TVajax.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    popUp.showAtLocation(findViewById(R.layout.popup), Gravity.BOTTOM, 10, 10);
                    popUp.setWidth(170);
                    popUp.setHeight(70);
                    title.setText("Perfect!");
                    title.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                    message.setText("points: "+points);
                    message.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
                    close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
                    stats.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Intent statss=new Intent();
                            startActivity(statss);
                        }
                    });

                }
                else{
                    messageBox(answers,answera);
                }


            }
        });
    }

    private void initialize() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TVajax= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TVajax);
        hint1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Hint1);
        hint2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Hint2);
        check = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Bcheck);
        right = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BshowLetters);
        used = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BusedLetters);
        stats = new Button(this);
        stats.findViewById(R.id.bStattistics);
        close = new Button(this);
        close.findViewById(R.id.bClose);
        title = new TextView(this);
        title.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        message = new TextView(this);
        message.findViewById(R.id.tvMessage);
        popUp =new PopupWindow(this);

    }
```

and this popup.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bStattistics"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
        android:text="Stats" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bClose"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/bStattistics"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bStattistics"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tvMessage"
        android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
        android:text="Close" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bStattistics"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tvMessage"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="40dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am trying to do PopupWindow and set the popup contentView to R.layout.popup (the popup.xml) and there is no window that is diaplayed

this are the logs:

```
06-30 10:48:06.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1856): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-30 10:48:06.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1856): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-30 10:48:06.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1856):     at com.app.Ajax$1.onClick(Ajax.java:222)
06-30 10:48:06.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1856):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
06-30 10:48:06.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1856):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
06-30 10:48:06.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1856):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-30 10:48:06.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1856):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-30 10:48:06.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1856):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-30 10:48:06.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1856):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-30 10:48:06.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1856):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-30 10:48:06.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1856):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-30 10:48:06.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1856):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-30 10:48:06.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1856):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-30 10:48:06.410: E/AndroidRuntime(1856):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

please help me with that problem

thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Your error clearly shows null pointer exception.
I assume you are trying to get answer from Text view.  **answer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ETajax);**  Where is ETajax in your popup.xml? I do not see it.. May be this is the reason for null pointer exception.

Comment: the ETajax is in the ajax.xml and it's not the point here.. I want that in the ajax.xml screen when something will happen the popup window will be up in the bottom of the screen and the popup window will look like the popup.xml

Comment: is your Ajax class in correct format or is it latest. Error log shows error as : Ajax.java:251 . When i put your code in my editor ,, line 251 is empty containing only '}'

Comment: I tried to run the app again and got new logs and the error changed to: Ajax.java.222 that in the code is: `popUp.showAtLocation(findViewById(R.layout.popup), Gravity.BOTTOM, 200, 200);`

Comment: popUp is null.I did'nt saw any where you initialize your popup.

Comment: I add line in the initialize method `popUp =new PopupWindow(this);` - and the logs changed to Ajax.java:223 that is: `title.setText("Perfect!");`... what's the problem now?

Comment: since your title is also in popup, so  title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTitle); will give null.You cannot do this at initialize.  do:  popup.findViewById. Null pointer exceptions are easier to tackel.. use break point to see what things are null and initialize them properly

Comment: I initialized the textViews and the buttons and there is no popupWindow.. what can I do? I edited the code..